# Redução de imagens no Firebird

Tags: imagem, firebird, redimensionamento

Tenho um banco Firebird com algumas imagens salvas em alta definição, alguém alguém conhece um método para reduzir as imagens sem precisar tira-las do banco?

Comment: Não tem jeito de reduzir diretamente no banco. Mas você pode escrever um programa para manipular as imagens.

Comment: Entendo, vou ver o que consigo fazer, obrigado!